# How to add volume number of encyclopedia entry in biblatex using apa style?

Tags: biblatex, citing, apa-style

I am using APA 7th for my thesis with `biblatex`. I recently noticed, that the volume numbers do not appear in the bibliography entries whenever I cite an encyclopedia entry or multi-volume book. How to add this?

My current MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[american, bidi=basic]{babel}

\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=apa,
    sortcites=true,
    backref=true,
    backrefstyle=three,
    abbreviate=true,
    block=space
]{biblatex}
\DeclareFieldFormat{apacase}{#1} % Title casing in APA

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@book{ej,
  title = {Encyclopaedia {Judaica}},
  editor = {Skolnik, Fred and Berenbaum, Michael},
  date = {2007},
  edition = {2},
  publisher = {Thomson Gale},
  location = {Detroit},
  isbn = {978-0-02-866097-4},
}
@inreference{ej:plants,
  title = {Plants},
  booktitle = {Encyclopaedia {Judaica}},
  author = {Feliks, Jehuda},
  editor = {Skolnik, Fred and Berenbaum, Michael},
  date = {2007},
  edition = {2},
  volume = {16},
  pages = {219-225},
  publisher = {Thomson Gale},
  location = {Detroit},
  isbn = {978-0-02-865944-2},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\parencite{ej}
\parencite{ej:plants}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This will result in the following:
[image]

But I would like the result like this:
[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: Not related to the issue, but `style=apa, citestyle=apa, bibstyle=apa,` is completely equivalent to `style=apa,` (`style` sets both `citestyle` and `bibstyle` to the same value). You should also drop the `sorting=nyt,` if you use `style=apa,` since the style comes with its own APA-compliant sorting scheme.

Comment: If you can find a rule in the APA manual that shows that the output you want is the output APA wants, you may want to report this as a bug at https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/issues.